# How to measure send and receive data size through the web service(wcf)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web

I'm new to Web services i need to know some method which I can use to measure send and receive data size through the web service because  i need to catch send data and receive data size is equal or not.Please help me if someone have better solution for this kind of problem.

Thanks

Comment: You do not have to worry about this.  WCF operations will not send a partial amount of data.  Either it will complete fully, or it won't and an exception will be generated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,but when data transfer time internet connection lost and reconnect if data can lost or it also handle by WCF ?

Comment: As I said, either the entire operation will complete, or it won't.  If the connection is lost, you won't get anything.